# people editor no match text

Tags: validation, sharepoint-2007, peoplepicker

I am creating one sharepoint webpart and it has one sharepoint people editor control. this is an required field. So i am using required field validator for validating the people editor control. But my problem is that when i am entering some junk data (eg: njhdfhfb), and then hit enter, it shows the validation message of **"No exact match was found."**. and also my validation message **Select an employee or group**. In my case i needs only my own validation message. But not the control message. How we can avoid this control validation message. Please help me for this. i had tried many ways.. but its not working. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above case the validator did not find any users and that is why it showed you the error message. You don't have to use a required field validator use `AllowEmpty` property and set its value to True.

You can disable to Validator using [ValidatorEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.entityeditor.validatorenabled.aspx) property.

Comment: but in my requirement, the client specified that we should use the required field validator for validating this control. And also i had tried the second methos that you specified. I set to validatorenabled to false.. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Well its your job to do it properly. just because Client asked means :-) Explain to the client that this is the best method. You can see your own Error Message and then use the existing property than making it complex.